# Хостинг для бота telegram

Tags: хостинг, telegram-bot, telegram

Написал рабочего бота для telegram на python. Теперь нужно сделать так, что бы он постоянно работал. Подскажите хостинг для этого.

Comment: Если денег мало, то VDS,а если много, то Дедик

Comment: Любой VDS по вкусу

Comment: Вот здесь есть подборка, посмотрите https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Where-to-host-Telegram-Bots#vps

Comment: Любой VDS/VPS. Также в интернете видел бесплатные варианты для личных проектов, названия не помню. Также можно купить себе микрокомпьютер (Raspberry Pi, Orange Pi, ...) и на нем запустить.

Comment: heroku.com, есть бесплатный тариф